# How to execute a delete query that includes a varchar and datetime field in the WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hello i try to delete from a Table where i need to access a varchar note field and an datetimefield.

Here is the Code:

```
DateTime test = (DateTime)powerPlant.timestamp;
string DateUS = test.ToString("s");

string deletePowerPlant = 
  String.Format(
    "DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblSPpowerPlants] WHERE [timestamp] = CONVERT(datetime,"+ DateUS +",111) AND [note] = {0};",
    note);

SqlCommand sqlDelete = new SqlCommand(deleteComponents, sqlConnection);
sqlDeletePowerPlant.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlDeletePowerPlant.CommandText = deleteComponents;
sqlDeletePowerPlant.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And yes normally i would use sql parameters but i want to know how it would work without parameters just to test it out becouse somehow it must be possible. I tried to google it and with some other forum and some blogs but had no luck.

Thx for your help and sorry for my english.

**EDIT**

The Field timestamp is a Datetime in the table.
The note is a nvarchar in the Table. And i just want to use it once so i can say i know how to do it without parameters. I know its bad....

Comment: You need to put `'`s around your `{0}`, but other than that what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: the format specifier 111 is Japanese `jjjj/mm/tt`, according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx). Did you mean 101?

Comment: Another possible source of error could be that you compare datetime objects. That leads to comparison of date AND time, so you may use DATE() function of sql instance to just compare on dates, not on time as well.

Comment: Are you sure 'timestamp' is of type `DateTime` and not of type `timestamp` which is actually used for versioning rows? See [Timestamp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx). `normally i would use sql parameters but i want to know how it would work without parameters ` - Why?? What purpose does that have? If you want to test your query then run it in Sql Server Management Studio but you should always code with parameters.

Comment: You have a string variable `deletePowerPlant` which you set, but then you assign the command text a different variable `deleteComponents`.... The style you need is 126 which is the ISO format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss, and you are missing single quotes. Finally, this is a waste of everyone's time, you know the correct way of doing it. You could do this inefficiently, incorrectly, and dangerously in hundreds of different ways, why do you only want to master this bad practice?

Comment: @GarethD thx for the tipp didnt notice it. I dont want to master the bad practice i just want to know how its possible. So i can say i have done it at least one time. Its just for test purpose. Would never use it at the job or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to make sure there is no dependency on server operating system locale. So if you use a certain format (111 in your case) in the SQL query, you should use the .NET equivalent to convert your date to a string:

```
string DateUS = test.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

For details about the formats that the `CONVERT` function supports, see here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx

As you stated yourself in the question, using a (strongly typed) SqlParameter is the preferred way to go. Failing to so so may result in sql injection vulnerabilities.

Given that `note` is a text column, single quotes and escaping will be required:

```
String.Format(
    "DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblSPpowerPlants] WHERE [timestamp]=CONVERT(datetime,'{0}',111) AND [note]='{1}'",
    DateUS
    note.Replace("'","''").Replace(@"\",@"\\")
);
```

If you store time-of-day too, the comparison with `=` will not affect records with nonzero time component.

Comment: With the tipp from GarethD and yours it works thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Put some string qualifiers in there

DateTime test = (DateTime)powerPlant.timestamp;
        string DateUS = test.ToString("s");

```
    string deletePowerPlant = String.Format("DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblSPpowerPlants] WHERE [timestamp] = CONVERT(datetime,'"+ DateUS +"',111) AND [note] = '{0}';", note);
    SqlCommand sqlDelete = new SqlCommand(deleteComponents, sqlConnection);
    sqlDeletePowerPlant.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlDeletePowerPlant.CommandText = deleteComponents;
    sqlDeletePowerPlant.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But really.  Use parameterized queries

Comment: the funny thing is i just tried it on the sql server and there it works. Really strange....